# Difference between edit and site layout in DNN 9

Tags: dotnetnuke

Hi I have a very basic question in DNN 9. Can you guys explain me the difference between edit and site layout in DNN 9.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which specific DNN 9 version you are using.  I'll assume 9.2.0, which includes the Personal Bar control panel.

"Edit" mode is entered by clicking the pencil icon at the bottom of the persona bar.  When you are in edit mode, you have additional options along the bottom to add modules or edit page settings.  Edit mode also shows outlines (surrounded by dotted borders) of the content panes into which you can place modules.  Edit mode also exposes controls that allow you to edit individual modules.  You need to mouse over a module to see them.

I'm not aware of a "Site Layout" mode in DNN 9.2.0.  Older versions of DNN did have a mode that shows the page along with the locations of the content panes.  It doesn't show module content.

Comment: I was asking about edit layout and site layout option in themes. I am using DNN 9.2.0. I am setting one skin for edit layout and another skin for site layout so what that means setting two skin for edit layout and site layout?